# Returning from decorator function to Member function in a class

Tags: python

I have written a decorator function which is working fine when I decorate to a normal function but when I decorated to a member function in class its throwing TypeError: print_cmd() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

The decorator function is working fine with normal function but same is not working for a member function of class

```
ss=[]
def deco(func):
   def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
       for i in new_arg:
            "Do some operation"  
       return func(','.join(ss))
   return new_func
class aaa:   
   @deco
   def print_cmd(self,cmd):
       print cmd

ii=aaa()
ii.print_cmd('hello,ff,are')
```

TypeError: print_cmd() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: can you put also your @deco ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly call the wrapped function with its original arguments, try this code instead:

```
return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The original code calls the wrapped function with a single string argument, and not the original function's arguments:

```
return func(','.join(ss))
```

Comment: My intention is to refactor the cmd and if I'm passing back *args,**kwargs.I wont get the modified cmd which is ','.join(ss)

Comment: This decorator is working fine if im using with normal function,Im getting issue with member function in class

Comment: It's not working on member functions in a class because they accept more than 1 argument. Try your decorator on any function which accepts more than 1 argument and it won't work.
It will also prevent a decorated function from working as it should because it does not send the original argument, but the string (which consists of the element of the list ss) that you are creating.